# How to add html tag inside trans directive?

Tags: email-templates, transactional-mail, translate

I am trying to add html `<a>` tag inside `{{trans''}}` but, I am getting the wrong output.
Below is how I am trying to do it.

```
<div class="register-button">
    {{trans'<a href="%reset_password_url">Reset Password</a>'reset_password_url=$reset_password_url|raw}}
    </div>
```

And the output I am getting is below.

[image: tag is not visible in output]

I need the output where `<a>` tag is visible inside output.

[image]

How can I achieve that output?

Comment: Try this <div class="register-button">
    {{trans"<a href='%reset_password_url'>"Rest Password"</a>"reset_password_url=$reset_password_url|raw}}
    </div>

Comment: Nope, that did not help

Comment: Might be the problem of <?php opening and closing, do check.

Comment: No this is an html email template. There is no phtml in that file.